# "I want you in/on/at/for an important topic"

Tags: prepositions

which sentence is correct :

> 1. I want you **in** an important topic
> 2. I want you **on** an important topic
> 3. I want you **at** an important topic
> 4. I want you **for** an important topic

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what would be meant by any of the prepositions, unless previous conversation had justified a short-hand expression like "want you [preposition] topic".

Here are some expressions that would be idiomatic:

I want your opinion **on** an important topic.
I want you to work **on** an important assignment.
I want you **for** an important assignment/job.
I want [to have] you **at** an important meeting.
I want [to have] you **in** the task group.

Now, your first example sentence with "on" could be used in a context like this:

> I've assigned Smedley to address the topic of capital expenditures, and Parkhurst will be writing about investor confidence. I want you **on** an important topic.

In that example, what was said before makes it clear that the boss means "work on" or "write on", so the short-hand expression has a clear meaning that it doesn't have in isolation.

Comment: I meant the expression of needing a friend to tell him something important

Comment: I don't think any of the prepositions would make that idiomatic. Just say "I need to talk to you about something important.",, or just as you've put it, "I need to tell you something important." If you're talking to  a friend, saying "...an important topic" would sound a bit  stiff.